# UI-Router : Pages & Posts routing are interfering

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

Here is the setup :

```
$stateProvider

// MAIN
    .state('app', {
         abstract: true,
     })

// PAGES  -  All pages are always children of a parent page
    .state('app.page', {
         url: '/{level1}',      <--- how to exclude /products from {level1} ?
    })
    .state('app.page.child', {
         url: '/{level2}',
    })

// POSTS
    .state('app.posts', {
         url: '/products',     //  <-- Error, not isolated
    })
    .state('app.posts.type', {
         url: '/{type}',
    })
```

Problem:  When i lead to a child post it is considered has a child page.

Is there a way to say to exclude `products` from {level1} ?

Or any other idea / better way of approaching the problem ?

Thank you !

Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, changing the order of the statements makes it work...

```
$stateProvider

// MAIN
    .state('app', {
         abstract: true,
     })

// POSTS
    .state('app.posts', {
         url: '/products',
    })
    .state('app.posts.type', {
         url: '/{type}',
    })

// PAGES
    .state('app.level1', {
         url: '/{level1}', 
    })
    .state('app.level1.level2', {
         url: '/{level2}',
    })
```

I just inverted Posts and Pages declaration.
Any other tips are welcome!